# get an average image from multiple Emgu.Cv.Mat

Tags: c#, image, emgucv

I have to get an average image from a set of images using Emgu.CV. The Input Images are `Image<Gray,byte> (1 channel, 1 byte pixels)`. I have written this method but it does not seam to work:

```
public static Mat GetAverage(List<Mat> matrices)
{
    //where to store the result
    Mat result = new Mat(matrices.First().Size, 
                        DepthType.Cv16U, 
                        matrices.First().NumberOfChannels); 

    //where to store the partial sums
    using (Mat elementwiseSum = new Mat(matrices.First().Size, 
                                    DepthType.Cv64F, 
                                    matrices.First().NumberOfChannels)) 
    {
        // loop over the input
        foreach (Mat matrix in matrices)
        {
            // sum each image to the partial sum
            CvInvoke.Accumulate(matrix, elementwiseSum); 
        }
        // convert to UInt16 and scale by the number of input images
        elementwiseSum.ConvertTo(result, 
                                DepthType.Cv16U, 
                                1.0 / matrices.Count); 
    }
    return result;
}
```

Both `elementwiseSum` and `result` seam to be black images... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How do you visualize elementwiseSum and result? Are you using Imshow?

Comment: I tried to run your code with 2 images and I see strange result. When I use `CvInvoke.Imshow()`, the `elementwiseSum` is completely white and the `result ` is completely black. But when I show them to a `PictureBox`, it showed the combination of the 2 images.

Comment: All the `Mat` in the `List` have the same size?

Comment: Dear all,
I visualized the results by drawing the Mat.Bitmapin a  windows.Form.PictureBox
and yes the images have the same size (I use the same picture multiple times for testing the method)

Comment: Usually there may be problems when trying to directly visualize images with depth > 8bit. Try to convert your result image to Cv8U and visualize it.